# Auto clicking a button after countdown on Android

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I am new at coding and right now I am looking for an advice. Lets say there is an app (on Android) with a countdown, and after that countdown hits zero, a button appears. I was thinking of creating an accessibility service, that would immediately hit that button after it appears. Are there any ways to do that?. What would you advice, where to start, and how to easier implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just perform the same code when the countdown hits zero as if the user clicks on the button.

So for example in your onClickListener of your button you call the function doSomething(). Now what you can do is just call the same function doSomething() when your timer hits zero

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I guess I didn't explain the problem quite well. The thing is that it is not my app with the countdown. So there is a timer in another app, after which there appears a button that need to be clicked as fast as possible (human touch is a bit slow though).